# Appengine (Python) "Push to Deploy" app.yaml Location

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, deployment, app.yaml

I have an app with the following file structure

```
app
├── src 
│    ├── app.yaml
│    ├── {other}
│    ├── {.py source}
│    └── {files}
├── {{other}}
├── {{meta}}
└── {{data}}
```

Before "Push to Deploy", I deploy my app like this

```
cd app/; appcfg.py --oauth2 update src
```

I would like to set up "Push to Deploy" but seems like it requires the app.cfg at the root directory like this.

```
app
├── app.yaml
├── {other}
├── {.py source}
├── {files}
├── {{other}}
├── {{meta}}
└── {{data}}
```

Is there a way to use "Push to Deploy" without moving all the {other .py source files} to root directory?

I'm OK with moving the app.yaml file to root. However, what change in the app.cfg is required?

This is my `app.cfg` file

```
application: myApp
version: v1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: main.application

- url: /tasks/.*
  script: tasks.Update.app
  login: admin

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: resources/images/static/favicon.ico
  upload: resources/images/static/favicon.ico

- url: /redirect/.*
  script: Redirect.app
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put all of your Python source files in a package (a subdirectory with a `__init__.py` file in it), then refer to your handlers by their package path.

```
app
-- app.yaml
-- myapp
   -- __init__.py
   -- main.py
   ...
```

The `app.yaml` simply uses the path like so:

```
...
handlers:
- url: /
  script: myapp.main.application
```